# Uploaded status error using fetch in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, upload, fetch, localhost

I have tried uploading an excel file using fetch in ReactJS on localhost:8080 but I'm getting the upload status as failed. How can I resolve this problem.

This is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
            file: '', 
            msg: ''
          };
          }

        onFileChange = (event) => {
          this.setState({
            file: event.target.files[0]
          });
        }
        
        uploadFileData = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.setState({msg: ''});
      
          let data = new FormData();
          data.append('file', this.state.file);
      
          fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
          }).then(response => {
            this.setState({msg: "File successfully uploaded"});
          }).catch(err => {
            this.setState({error: err});
          });
      
        }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
          <div id="container">
              <h1>File Upload Example using React</h1>
              <h3>Upload a File</h3>
              <h4>{this.state.msg}</h4>

              <input onChange={this.onFileChange} 
                      type="file" 
                      accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>

              <button disabled={!this.state.file} onClick={this.uploadFileData}>Upload</button>
                </div>
      </>
    );
    }
}
  

export default App;
```

Can anyone help me fix the problem which is making the upload file status failed

This is Github Repo:[https://github.com/BhupathiVenkataSaiCharan/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch](http://I%20have%20tried%20uploading%20an%20excel%20file%20using%20fetch%20in%20ReactJS%20on%20localhost:8080%20but%20I%27m%20getting%20the%20upload%20status%20as%20failed.%20How%20can%20I%20resolve%20this%20problem.%20%20This%20is%20my%20App.js%20%20import%20React,%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20%22react%22;%20import%20%27./App.css%27;%20%20class%20App%20extends%20Component%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(props);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file:%20%27%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msg:%20%27%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onFileChange%20=%20(event)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file:%20event.target.files%5B0%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uploadFileData%20=%20(event)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bmsg:%20%27%27%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20data%20=%20new%20FormData();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data.append(%27file%27,%20this.state.file);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fetch(%27http://localhost:8080/upload%27,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method:%20%27POST%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body:%20data%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).then(response%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bmsg:%20%22File%20successfully%20uploaded%22%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).catch(err%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Berror:%20err%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20render()%7B%20%20%20%20%20return(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22container%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EFile%20Upload%20Example%20using%20React%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%3EUpload%20a%20File%3C/h3%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch4%3E%7Bthis.state.msg%7D%3C/h4%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20onChange=%7Bthis.onFileChange%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type=%22file%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accept=%22application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet%22/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20disabled=%7B!this.state.file%7D%20onClick=%7Bthis.uploadFileData%7D%3EUpload%3C/button%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/%3E%20%20%20%20%20);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20export%20default%20App;%20Can%20anyone%20help%20me%20fix%20the%20problem%20which%20is%20making%20the%20upload%20file%20status%20failed%20%20This%20is%20Github%20Repo:https://github.com/BhupathiVenkataSaiCharan/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch%20%20This%20is%20the%20Hosted%20ReactJS%20application%20link%20:https://bhupathivenkatasaicharan.github.io/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch/)

This is the Hosted ReactJS application link :[https://bhupathivenkatasaicharan.github.io/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch/](http://I%20have%20tried%20uploading%20an%20excel%20file%20using%20fetch%20in%20ReactJS%20on%20localhost:8080%20but%20I%27m%20getting%20the%20upload%20status%20as%20failed.%20How%20can%20I%20resolve%20this%20problem.%20%20This%20is%20my%20App.js%20%20import%20React,%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20%22react%22;%20import%20%27./App.css%27;%20%20class%20App%20extends%20Component%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(props);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file:%20%27%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msg:%20%27%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onFileChange%20=%20(event)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file:%20event.target.files%5B0%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uploadFileData%20=%20(event)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bmsg:%20%27%27%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20data%20=%20new%20FormData();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data.append(%27file%27,%20this.state.file);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fetch(%27http://localhost:8080/upload%27,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method:%20%27POST%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body:%20data%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).then(response%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bmsg:%20%22File%20successfully%20uploaded%22%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).catch(err%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Berror:%20err%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20render()%7B%20%20%20%20%20return(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22container%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EFile%20Upload%20Example%20using%20React%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%3EUpload%20a%20File%3C/h3%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch4%3E%7Bthis.state.msg%7D%3C/h4%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20onChange=%7Bthis.onFileChange%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type=%22file%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accept=%22application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet%22/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20disabled=%7B!this.state.file%7D%20onClick=%7Bthis.uploadFileData%7D%3EUpload%3C/button%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/%3E%20%20%20%20%20);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20export%20default%20App;%20Can%20anyone%20help%20me%20fix%20the%20problem%20which%20is%20making%20the%20upload%20file%20status%20failed%20%20This%20is%20Github%20Repo:https://github.com/BhupathiVenkataSaiCharan/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch%20%20This%20is%20the%20Hosted%20ReactJS%20application%20link%20:https://bhupathivenkatasaicharan.github.io/ExcelFileUploadWithFetch/)

[This is the error I can't solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPOss.png)

Comment: Do you have some api here http://localhost:8080/upload? And what the error did you get?

Comment: Hey @Oleg I have uploaded the image of my problem please check

Answer (score 0):

you must set your content type

```
headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
```